# mssql_bind not working in heterogenous server

Tags: php, sql-server, bind, procedure, php-mssql

I have PHP on linux server and mssql 2005 on windows server, whenever i try to connect php with mssql , while executing stored procedure it give me error , my code is as below

```
mssql_connect('DBSERVER', 'sa', 'password');  
mssql_select_db('tst');

// Create a new stored prodecure
$stmt = mssql_init('sp_report');

// Bind the field names
mssql_bind($stmt, '@username',  'test',  SQLVARCHAR,  false,  false,  60);
mssql_bind($stmt, '@name',      'johndoe',  SQLVARCHAR,  false,  false,  60);
mssql_bind($stmt, '@age',       19,       SQLINT1,     false,  false,   3);

// Execute
mssql_execute($stmt);
```

How ever the code below is running fine

```
 exec sp_report 'test','johndoe','19'
```

If i host php also on same server(the server where database resides) both codes are running fine.

Comment: it says mssql_init is invalid

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that there's no MS-SQL driver for PHP installed on the Linux server.